# Eclipse Neon (Java EE IDE) Javascript Editor Broken

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jakarta-ee, development-environment, eclipse-neon

### Problem Description

Opening up a file (app.js) with the **JavaScript Editor** gives me the error: "Editor could not be initialized."

**Details:**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAException.getEcmaError()Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.esprima.EsprimaParser.parse(EsprimaParser.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.dom.ASTParser.createAST(ASTParser.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.buildStructure(CompilationUnit.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(JavaElement.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.BecomeWorkingCopyOperation.executeOperation(BecomeWorkingCopyOperation.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:742)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:802)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.becomeWorkingCopy(CompilationUnit.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.createFileInfo(CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.java:975)
    at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider.connect(TextFileDocumentProvider.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.connect(CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.java:1190)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractTextEditor.java:4178)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.doSetInput(StatusTextEditor.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.java:1466)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.internalDoSetInput(JavaEditor.java:2173)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.doSetInput(JavaEditor.java:2146)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor.doSetInput(CompilationUnitEditor.java:1306)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$5.run(AbstractTextEditor.java:3154)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:437)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$14.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2184)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.internalInit(AbstractTextEditor.java:3172)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.init(AbstractTextEditor.java:3197)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.initialize(EditorReference.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:319)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:966)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:931)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:975)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1317)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer$1.handleEvent(LazyStackRenderer.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4813)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:617)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1214)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3261)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$25(WorkbenchPage.java:3176)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3158)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3117)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenWithMenu.openEditor(OpenWithMenu.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenWithMenu.lambda$0(OpenWithMenu.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenWithMenu$$Lambda$65/49673515.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4410)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4228)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3816)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:687)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
```

- Closing and attempting to reopen the file generates a blank tab.
- Attempting to open other files also generates a blank tab.
- Opening more than one tab generates a `NullPointerException`.
- Restarting Eclipse restores Eclipse to a functional state.
- Using the JS Editor (Chrome icon) in place of the JavaScript editor seems to circumvent the problem (only works if the above error has not already been triggered).

  - I'm afraid using the JS Editor will prevent me from using other plugins which rely on the JavaScript editor to work.

---

#### What I tried

- Uninstalling unsigned plugins ([AngularJS Eclipse](https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse))
- Reinstalling Eclipse Neon
- Reinstalling unsigned plugins (AngularJS Eclipse - same as above)

---

#### Notes

In order to launch Eclipse Neon in the first place, the following line was removed from the `eclipse.ini`:

```
-vmargs
```

---

#### Temporary Solution

As seen in [howlger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38134238/3650944), this is an issue caused by the JavaScript Editor not properly handling a parsing exception.

This is a trimmed down version of the original file, demonstrating the problem:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('TestModule', []);

    app.controller("TestController", [ '$http', function($http){

    ]});
})();
```

- The [online Esprima parser](http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html) helped me find that I had misplaced a square bracket on line 6.

Here is the code after the fix:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('TestModule', []);

    app.controller("Test Controller", [ '$http', function($http) {

    } ]);
})();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eclipse Neon contains the JavaScript Development Tools (JSDT) 2.0 which use [Esprima](http://esprima.org/) as parser. (Esprima is written in JavaScript and executed by JSDT via Nashorn.) In your case, Esprima fails to parse your JavaScript file and JSDT 2.0 are not very robust (have no fallback strategy) to handle this kind of problem. Try to [parse your file with Esprima online](http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html). JSDT are aware of these Esprima problems and [plan to replace it in an upcoming version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UxGwu2adzIc) ([Eclipse bug 497249](https://bugs.eclipse.org/497249)), maybe in Neon.1 in September. Unfortunately, as long as JSDT fails to parse your file, you can not use the JSDT JavaScript editor.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried the online parser and found the error. Now I can open the file just fine. It never occurred to me that JSDT not handling the parser's exception gracefully was the cause of the bug.

Comment: I was finally able to solve it; see my answer and if you don't mind, add a comment to your answer. Checking for new JDK builds is something I completely overlooked.

Answer (score 3):

This issue was completely resolved by installing the latest JDK. Even the part where I had to remove `-vmargs` from the `eclipse.ini` to launch Eclipse Neon in the first place.

**`java -version` before:**

```
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

**`java -version` after:**

```
java version "1.8.0_92"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Worked after updating to latest JDK.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, i resolved my issue by changing the version of java from 1.6 to 1.8 in eclipse.actually i have java verison 1.8 but my eclipse is poiting to 1.6 version , so i changed that veriosn from 1.6  to 1.8 resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same error just now. After one hour I found out it was because of a json format mistake. I did not put "," after each element of an array.

```
$scope.finalResultList = [
    {page:1, coors:'1,2,3,4', name:'aaa'}
    {page:2, coors:'1,2,3,4', name:'bbb'}
    {page:3, coors:'1,2,3,4', name:'ccc'}
];
```

Eclipse was sooooo smart to find that out and gave me a very very very easy to understand error message. Thank you Eclipse!

So, you might have some mistake in your code. Fix it with some other editor then come back to Eclipse.